# Get category ID for AJAX 'Load More' function (Wordpress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to filter results of an AJAX infinite scroll feature/Load More button on a Wordpress posts page.

If I hard code in the Category ID as an argument for `WP_Query`, it works, however I don't seem to be able to find a way to get the current collection of post's category ID.

Here's my load_more php function:

```
// Load More
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more');

function load_more() {

    $paged = $_POST["page"]+1;

    $current_category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post' => 'post',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat'  => $current_category
    ));

  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

  ?>

  <article class="post-box" id="content">
    <div class="post-img-box">
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        the_post_thumbnail();

        } else { ?>

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/blank.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <p class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
  </article>

  <?php endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata();

  die();

}
```

It's the `$current_category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();` that isn't right/working.

Comment: I have also tried a few other apporaches, for example: `$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); $current_category = $category->cat_ID;` but this also doesn't work and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in a roundabout way:

1) Add `$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');` to the top of the wordpress theme page. (index.php in my case).

2) Add `data-category="<?php echo esc_attr($cat_id); ?>"` to the Load More html button tag.

3) In the jQuery .ajax request add the `data-category` to the data request object:

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-more-btn', function() {

        event.preventDefault();

        var that = $(this);
        var page = that.data('page');
        var newPage = page+1;
        var ajaxurl = that.data('url');
        var cat = that.data('category');
        console.log(page);

        $.ajax({

          url : ajaxurl,
          type : 'post',
          data : {
            cat : cat,
            page : page,
            action : 'load_more'
          },
          error: function(response) {
            console.log(reponse);
          },
          success : function(response) {
            that.data('page', newPage);
            $('.more-posts').append(response);

          }

        });

      })
```

4) Add `$current_category = $_POST['cat'];` to the php `load_more()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing onScroll infinite post loads on homepage and archive pages. I did it simply as below:

1. Localize current category ID

   ```
   $data = array(
   'processor' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/loopHandler.php',
   'category' => get_query_var('cat'),
   'loader'    => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/ajax-loader.gif');
   wp_localize_script('ajaxLoop', 'localized_data', $data);
   ```
2. Post the category ID to query_posts

   ```
   data: {numPosts : 1, pageNumber: page, category: localized_data.category },
   ```
3. Build query args

   ```
   $posts = query_posts(array(
      'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
      'paged'          => $page,
      'cat'             => $_GET['category']
   ));
   ```